# topic /scan of hokuyo node can't link to the /base_scan of gmapping node

Tags: ros, navigation, hokuyo-node, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I launch gmapping node and hokuyo node, the topic /scan of hokuyo node can't link to the /base_scan of gmapping node.

Do I miss something ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10996/topic-/scan-of-hokuyo-node-can%27t-link-to-the-/base_scan-of-gmapping-node/) by [JosephChen](https://answers.ros.org/users/980/josephchen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2011-08-23

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You just need to remap (rename) the topic.  It is explained on wiki in [Remapping Arguments](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Remapping%20Arguments) .

For you specific case, either:

- Running from command-line, `rosrun hokuyo_node hokuyo_node scan:=base_scan`
- In launch script, `<node pkg="hokuyo_node" type="hokuyo_node" name="hokuyo" > <remap from="scan" to="base_scan" /> </node>`

---

Originally posted by [Nick Armstrong-Crews](https://answers.ros.org/users/885/nick-armstrong-crews/) with karma: 481 on 2011-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-08-24**:
You don't need to do it yourself. You do need to provide the transform between base_link and base_laser by publishing the appropriate transform. You can easily do this with a static_transform_publisher if your laser is fixed with respect to the base. Gmapping can transform the scan itself with tf.

**Comment by [JosephChen](https://answers.ros.org/users/980/josephchen/) on 2011-08-24**:
Thank you ! Now it can link to the gmapping node. but I have one thing I don't understand, the /scan of hokuyo node is "base_laser" coordinate frame. Do I need to use tf to transform coordinate to robot's "base_link" coordinate frames, than input to the gmapping ?

**Comment by [zxh362989](https://answers.ros.org/users/18461/zxh362989/) on 2014-05-25**:
thank you for solving my problem!